# Javascript toggle hide and show buttons in a loop Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, laravel-5, hide

I am writing a Laravel 5 project with a comment section code below

```
@foreach($Comment as $Comment)
  <div id="comment-{!! $Comment->comments_id !!}" class="comment-wrapper">

     <div class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-xs" class="show">Show</div>
  <div class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-xs" class="hide">Hide</div>
  <div class="btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-xs" class="toggle">Toggle</div>

      <div class="watch" class="jumbotron alert-info">



         <ul class="list-group">
           <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">{!! $Comment->author  !!}</li>
           <li class="list-group-item"> {!! $Comment->text !!}</li>
           </ul>
             @if ($Comment->author == Auth::user()->name)
               <p><a href="{!! URL::route('deleteComment', $Comment->comments_id) !!}"  class=" btn-danger btn-xs" style="float:right">Delete</a></p>  



              @endif

        <h6><small>CREATED ON: {!! $Comment->created_at !!}</small></h6>
</div>
</div>
          @endforeach
```

and I have a javascript file which looks like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $('.show').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.comment-parent').find('.watch').show('slow');
});
 $('.hide').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.comment-parent').find('.watch').hide('slow');
});
 $('.toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.comment-parent').find('.watch').toggle('slow');
});

});
```

The trouble is the toggle/hide javascript function only works on one set of buttons and hides all of the comments.  I want to have the set of buttons that work for each comment individually.  I've tried to increment the watch class and buttons div id by adding 1 and incrementing it for each comment but can't get it to work.  Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Why do you have a `<dt>` tag inside an `<ul>`?

Comment: The `id` attribute for a element in html should be unique, you have the same value in a foreach loop, assign it to a class instead or give it a name with an integer next to it.

Comment: for styling is that not good?

Comment: I believe it's invalid HTML, you also have a `</dt>` and `</dl>` tag that pop out of nowhere. I reckon you probably want to go other you code and then run it through a html validator. Apologies if this comes across harsh, not trying to be annoying!

Comment: ok thanks that's what I was trying to do but must have got the syntax wrong.  what would be the correct way of doing that?

Comment: not at all mate I'm quite new at this and any criticism is constructive. Thanks

Comment: You only want to nest `<li>`s in `<ul>`s or `<ol>`s. `<dl>`s can be nested in `<dt>`s I believe. Awesome, I wish you all the best with your learning - that's the best attitude to have! And as for `id` attribute for html elements you only want them to have unique values for a given page.

Comment: I've edited my first post with updated html changes.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
$('#show').click(function () {
    $(this).next('.watch').show('slow');
});
```

Try same approach for other methods, so only the next first `div` with class of `watch` will be acted and also, you could have wrapped each set in a single parent container using a unique `id` attribute in addition to a `class`, for better grouping. For example:

```
@foreach($Comment as $Comment)
    <div id="comment-{{$comment->id}}" class="comment-wrapper">
        <div class="btn btn-lg btn-info btn-xs show">Show</div>
        <!-- More... -->
        <div class="watch" class="jumbotron alert-info">
            <!-- More... -->
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

This way, you could have done the `jQuery` slecting more specifically, for example:

```
$('#show').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.comment-parent').find('.watch').show('slow');
});
```

**Update** (Thanks to [haakym](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648247/haakym) for pointing me that): Also, an `id` must be unique so instead of using `id='show'` use it as a class and then use:

```
$('.show').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.comment-parent').find('.watch').show('slow');
});
```

Comment: You might want to move `id="show"` over to the class attribute, otherwise each div will have `id="show"` i.e. invalid html

Comment: Thanks @haakym, I actually didn't notice that `id` at all :-)

Comment: thanks fr your help, if I change the id to class none of the buttons work?

Comment: If you change id to class just swap out `#` for `.` in any jQuery

Comment: that's what I tried didn't work for some reason.  Will check to see if I made a mistake.

Comment: I can't see any problems, I've edited the code in my first post if you could have a look thanks.

Comment: ok so I've fixed the class problem by realising there was two classes but the jQuery The Alpha suggested to work